# Velocity: #set($var2 = "#springMessage($var1)")

Tags: spring-mvc, localization, internationalization, translation, velocity

I want to do something like this:

```
<head>
  <title>
    #set($windowTitleKey = $tiles.insertAttribute({'name':'window_title_key', 'ignore': true}))      
    #set($translatedPageName = "#springMessage($windowTitleKey)")        
    #springMessageText("SEO_page_title_default", [$translatedPageName])
  </title>
</head>
```

The first "set" line works, and so does the springMessageText line.

This line does NOT work: `#set($translatedPageName = "#springMessage($windowTitleKey)")`  It sets $translatedPageName to `$springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code)`.

What is another way to accomplish the goal of nested translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to code a custom helper.  What a hassle.  I look forward to abandoning Velocity entirely someday.

In Velocity view:

```
#set($windowTitleKey = $tiles.insertAttribute({'name':'window_title_key', 'ignore': true}))
#set($translatedPageName = $TranslationsHelper.getTranslation("$windowTitleKey"))
#springMessageText("SEO_window_title_default", ["$translatedPageName"])
```

In TranslationsHelper.java:

```
    public class TranslationsHelper extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource
    {    
            public static String getTranslation(String messageKey, Object[] args)
            {
                    MessageSource ms = getMessageSource();
                    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
                    return ms.getMessage(messageKey, args, locale);
            }
            public static MessageSource getMessageSource()
            {
                    WebApplicationContext webAppContext = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
                    return (MessageSource) webAppContext.getBean("messageSource");        
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is <s>love</s> [#evaluate](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/vtl-reference-guide.html#aevaluate_-_Dynamically_evaluates_a_string_or_reference)

Comment: I know about #evaluate but don't see where/how I'd use it here.  What are you saying that I should do?